# Can I customize the "Office365" link in Outlook for Office365?

Tags: outlook-web-app, microsoft-office-365

In the webclient for Outlook in O365, there is a link in the upper left-hand corner labled "Office365."  Is there any way to customize the url?

Comment: If the answers you were provided help you with your question, you should select one as an accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to point it to a different installation of Office Web Apps, then yes.  You can use WAC Discovery to point it to a different server as listed in the [integration guide](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj150495(v=exchg.150).aspx).

```
Set-OrganizationConfig -WACDiscoveryEndPoint https://Server1/hosting/discovery
```

If you are trying to send it somewhere arbitrary, it doesn't look like there is a built in supported way to change it.  I do notice a suspiciously interesting "WacUrlHostName" option in `ClientAccess\Owa\Web.conf`.

That being said, there is a [full API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp161135.aspx) to extend the OWA and Outlook 2013 experience which may be a better option than hacking around in undocumented config files.